# How to solve MySQL error "#1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row" in this case?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT SUM(`Total sale`) 
FROM `sales details` 
WHERE `Day` = "Sunday"
  AND `Shop ID` = (
    SELECT `Shop ID`
    FROM `shops` 
    WHERE `shops`.`Area Code` = (
      SELECT `Area Code` 
      FROM `distributors_areas` 
      WHERE `distributors_areas`.`Regional_Manager` = (
        SELECT `Name` 
        FROM `regional managers` 
        WHERE `regional managers`.`ID` = "REG_02"
      )
    )
  )
```

I want to get sum of `Total sale` where day is sunday and the shops are in the administrative area of regional manager "REG_02". So I compared shop id of sunday sales to shop ids of those areas (Area Code) which belongs to "RM_02". `shops` table has names of regional managers, So I compared them with the names in `regional managers` table to get "RM_002"'s name.

Comment: Save yourself a world of misery. Don't have spaces in table/column identifiers.

Answer (score 0):

The simple approach is to use `IN`:

```
SELECT SUM(sd.`Total sale`)
FROM `sales details` sd
WHERE sd.`Day` = 'Sunday' AND
      sd.`Shop ID` IN
          (SELECT s.`Shop ID`
           FROM `shops` s
           WHERE s.`Area Code` IN
                     (SELECT da.`Area Code`
                      FROM `distributors_areas` da
                      WHERE da.`Regional_Manager` IN 
                             (SELECT rm.`Name`
                              FROM `regional managers` rm
                              WHERE rm.`ID` = 'REG_02'
                             )
                     )
          );
```

A more sensible approach simply uses `JOIN`:

```
SELECT SUM(sd.`Total sale`)
FROM `sales details` sd JOIN
     `shops` s
     ON sd.`Shop ID` = s.`Shop ID` JOIN
     `distributors_areas` da
     ON s.`Area Code` = da.`Area Code` JOIN
     `regional managers` rm
     ON  da.Regional_Manager = rm.Name
WHERE sd.Day = 'Sunday' AND
      rm.ID = 'REG_02';
```

Notes:

- Use table aliases that are abbreviations for table names.  This makes queries easier to read and write.
- The *SQL* standard string delimiter is the single quote.  You should use that.  Double quotes have multiple purposes, so they are ambiguous.
- There is no need to use backticks for identifiers that are only letters, digits, and underscore.  They just make the query harder to write and read.
- Avoid using characters like spaces in names, so you do not need to escape the names.

Answer (score 0):

If you need  just one rows then you could use limit 1

```
SELECT SUM(`Total sale`) 
FROM `sales details` 
WHERE `Day` = "Sunday" AND `Shop ID` = ( 
    SELECT `Shop ID` 
    FROM `shops` WHERE `shops`.`Area Code` = ( 
        SELECT `Area Code` 
        FROM `distributors_areas` 
        WHERE `distributors_areas`.`Regional_Manager` = ( 
          SELECT `Name` 
          FROM `regional managers` 
          WHERE `regional managers`.`ID` = "REG_02"
          ORDER BY name 
          LIMIT 1 
        )
      ORDER by `Area Code` 
      LIMIT 1 
    ) 
)
```

if you need several result you should use IN

```
SELECT SUM(`Total sale`) 
FROM `sales details` 
WHERE `Day` = "Sunday" AND `Shop ID`  IN  ( 
    SELECT `Shop ID` 
    FROM `shops` WHERE `shops`.`Area Code` IN  ( 
        SELECT `Area Code` 
        FROM `distributors_areas` 
        WHERE `distributors_areas`.`Regional_Manager` IN = ( 
          SELECT `Name` 
          FROM `regional managers` 
          WHERE `regional managers`.`ID` = "REG_02"
        )
    )
)
```

but looking to your code seems you could avoid the subquery using  inner join

```
SELECT SUM(`Total sale`) 
FROM `sales details` 
INNER JOIN `shops` ON `shops`.`Shop ID`  = `sales details`. `Shop ID` 
INNER JOIN distributors_areas` ON distributors_areas`.`Area Code` = `shops`.`Area Code` 
INNER JOIN `regional managers` ON `regional managers` .`Name` = distributors_areas`.`Regional_Manager`
  and `regional managers`.`ID` = "REG_02"
```

WHERE `sales details`.`Day` = "Sunday"